# Perl script to open a file and read a string

Tags: perl

I know how to open a file and display entire content using perl script, but how can i read a string from file into a variable

Following is to open file and display entire content

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = '/home/abc/data.txt';
if (open(my $fh, '<', $filename)) {
  while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    print "$row\n";
  }
} else {
  warn "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
}
```

My requirement is

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl 
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $filename = '/home/abc/data.txt';
    my $foo = ""
    if (open(my $fh, '<', $filename)) {
     ---- Read test_reg_ip string from data.txt into variable 
         $foo=test_reg_ip;
    } else {
      warn "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
    }
    print "$foo\n";
```

Following is the input file data.txt

```
#############################################################################################
# mon_server_ip
# This parameter value should point to the IP address where the mon Server
# is installed
#############################################################################################
mon_server_ip = 127.0.0.1

#############################################################################################
# test_reg_ip
# This parameter value should point to the IP address where reg server is
# installed
#############################################################################################
test_reg_ip = 127.0.0.1

#############################################################################################
# mon_port
# This parameter value should point to the mon port 
#############################################################################################
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open (my $fh, "<", "file.txt") or die $!;
while(<$fh>){
    if ($_ = /test_reg_ip = (.*)/){
        my $ip = $1;
        print "IP is $ip\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code assumes a few things, but if the config entries are consistently the same, you could iterate the entire file and store all the config details in a hash in case you need more of them later:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, '<', 'in.txt'
  or die $!;

my %data;

while (<$fh>){
    if (/^(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)$/){
        $data{$1} = $2;
    }
}

print "$data{test_reg_ip}\n";

print "$data{mon_server_ip}\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

you need a regexp. try something like this:

```
if ($row =~ /test_reg_ip\s=\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})/) {
   my  $foo = $1; # your IP goes here, on the first (and only matched group)
}
```